# How to upload multiple photos in single Facebook post using Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

postResponse = await axios.post(`https://graph.facebook.com/${pageId}/photos`, {
url: payload.mediaUrls[0],
message: payload.post,
access_token: pageAccessToken,
});

I am using Graph API, This is my typescript code where payload.mediaUrls is an array of photos.
This code work fine for a single photo post but I want to post multiple photos in a post. So what changes are required

I have tried '/feed' end-point but not working

**Update 08/24/23 - by Daniel Vaca**

I'm also trying to figure out how to do this except I'm using the Facebook Javascript SDK. I tried something like this. And it upload multiple photos, but on separate posts. Is there a way to upload them all in a single post?

```
function postMultiplePhotosToPage(pageAccessToken, pageId, payload) {

  var photoBatch = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < payload.mediaUrls.length; i++) {
    var photoData = {
      method: 'POST',
      relative_url: pageId + '/photos',
      body: 'url=' + encodeURIComponent(payload.mediaUrls[i]) + '&message=' + payload.post,
    };
    photoBatch.push(photoData);
  }

  FB.api('/', 'POST', {
    batch: photoBatch,
    access_token: pageAccessToken
  }, function (responses) {
    console.log(responses);      
  });
}
```

This might be what the code would look like using axios:

```
async function postMultiplePhotosToPage(pageAccessToken, pageId, payload) {
  const photoBatch = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < payload.mediaUrls.length; i++) {
    const photoData = {
      method: 'POST',
      relative_url: `${pageId}/photos`,
      body: `url=${encodeURIComponent(payload.mediaUrls[i])}&message=${payload.post}`,
    };
    photoBatch.push(photoData);
  }

  const postResponse = await axios.post('https://graph.facebook.com/', photoBatch, {
    params: {
      batch: 'true',
      access_token: pageAccessToken,
    },
  });
}
```